# Is there a difference between normalizing vs. percentages when input data represents counts?

Tags: machine-learning, normalization, percentage, data-preprocessing

For example, say I have an input vector
`[0, 10, 0, 10, 20]` representing 0 of item 1, 10 of item 2, etc.

If I want to train on this data, is there some intuitive difference between the normalized vector:

`[ 0, 0.40824829, 0, 0.40824829, 0.81649658 ]`

versus a vector that's just the percentages of each relative to the number of observations?

`[ 0, 0.25, 0, 0.25, 0.5 ]`

Answer (score 1):

If you use a normalising constant than you could get roughly to the percentages. So very general spoken it‘s kind of the same, just with one more calculation.

An example would be entropy.

Comment: Note, however, that you would have a good deal more confidence in a percentage based on 400 observations than you would in a percentage based on 4 observations. You don't often gain much by throwing away relevant information.

Comment: That is for sure 